# Python Package Import Help Needed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have folder structure as shown in the below. I want to import `module1.py` file to my `script.py` file.

```
└── project
    ├── package1
    │   ├── module1.py
    │   └── module2.py
    └── package2
        ├── __init__.py
        └── script.py
```

Here is my `script.py` file

```
from package1.module1 import module1

mdl = module1()

print(mdl.get_name())
```

I have executed the `script.py` file as `python3 script.py` in the linux terminal. It says no module name `module1`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from package1.module1 import module1
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package1'
```

How Can I resolve this issue and maky my `script.py` executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add a blank file named `__init__.py` in your `package1` module.